# adding a element to an array of pointers within an object

Tags: java, arrays

```
class Family
{
    String name;
    Family[] siblings;
    Family mother;
    Family father;
    Family spouse;
}
public class Pointer
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Family saun = new Family();
        saun.name = "Saun Bladow";

        Family shannon = new Family();
        shannon.name = "Shannon Bladow";

        Family kailey = new Family();
        kailey.name = "Kailey Bladow";

        Family kyle = new Family();
        kyle.name = "Kyle Bladow";
        saun.siblings = {shannon, kailey, kyle};
    }
}
```

this code results in this error

```
illegal start of expression
        saun.siblings = {shannon, kailey, kyle};
                        ^
```

i know this code will work

```
        Family[] siblings = new Family[3];
        siblings[0] = shannon;
        siblings[1] = kailey;
        siblings[2] = kyle;
        saun.siblings = siblings;
```

but considering how big this family tree is going to be i'd prefer to use the first method but i can't figure out how to get it to work

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the syntax of the language it self, but in C# you can do something like this. I believe you have similar syntax in other languages as well, which is basically you create a new array and populate it.

```
saun.siblings = new Family [] {shannon, kailey, kyle};
```